# vim autocmd windowing: placement

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is it possible to place windowed plugins by .vimrc:

I tried:

```
autocmd vimenter * <C-W> <S-L>
autocmd vimenter * <C-W> <h>
```

But that **seems nonsense**. Vim doesn't not seem to be able to catch those shortcuts at vimenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
augroup vimrc
    autocmd!
    autocommand VimEnter * wincmd L|wincmd h
augroup END
```

See `:help :wincmd`.

Comment: Worked like a charm!